# Can I get a service to access the terminal?

Tags: command-line, terminal, systemd, services

I have a flask app that I wrote with Python and published with gunicorn service, but I learned that the services have no communication with the terminal, so I can't use pexpect module. Is there a way to make the service reach the terminal? The gunicorn service file and python code are available at [this Stack Overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717315/i-get-a-debug-worker-sigwinch-ignored-error-when-publishing-my-flask-applicat).

Nginx Conf;

```
server{
    server_name panel.xxxx.com;
    
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/root/flaskapp/flaskapp.sock;
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include proxy_params;

}
    location /phpmyadmin {
           root /usr/share/;
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
           location ~ ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
                   try_files $uri =404;
                   root /usr/share/;
                   fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
                   fastcgi_index index.php;
                   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
           }
           location ~* ^/phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
                   root /usr/share/;
           }
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.xxx.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/panel.xxx.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}server{
    if ($host = panel.xxxx.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name panel.xxxx.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Gunicorn3 Conf;

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn service
After=network.target

[Service]

User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/root/flaskapp
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 3 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app --timeout 300 --config /root/flaskapp/gunicorn.conf.py 


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

You can run the app within `screen` or `tmux` and connect from an "outside" terminal to that very virtual terminal.

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S gunicorn3 /usr/bin/gunicorn3 --workers 3 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app --timeout 300 --config /root/flaskapp/gunicorn.conf.py
```

If the app can be started manually then `systemd-run` with the option `--pty` may be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can I start a service file on screen or timux?

Comment: i start like this on screen screen  -L -Dm  sudo service gunicorn3 start but didnt work and
systemd-run --pty service guncirn3 start didnt work :(

Comment: @Apple Why would you use `-L -Dm`? Use `ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S your_command /your/command` and attach from the outside (with the same user) to it with `screen -S your_command -x`

Comment: I shared my gunicorn file and nginx file above How exactly should I edit the gunicorn so as not to have problems with nginx?

Comment: @Apple As I said: Prepend the value of `ExecStart` with `/usr/bin/screen -S gunicorn `

Comment: ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -S gunicorn3 --workers 3 --bind unix:flaskapp.sock -m 007 app:app --timeout 300 --config /root/flaskapp/gunicorn.conf.py
I do it this way, but I get an error.

Comment: @Apple What error?

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tbsc8m i took screenshoot

Comment: @Apple Of course, that does not work. You deleted your command... `/usr/bin/gunicorn3`

Comment: please don't be angry with me :( but how do i write exactly?There must be one ExecStart, right?

Comment: @Apple I added that to the answer.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/tbsou0 it gives an error like this

Comment: I did not test earlier under the right circumstances. As the SystemD unit does not have a tty, `screen` must be started with the options `-d -m`. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: I ran the script without the screen and it works so it is accessing the terminal. but I want to work in the background and read the outputs. It gives the same error in Tmux. SIGWINCH ignored in the gunicorn error log. If I can allow SIGWINCH everything is resolved.